# MissingManifestResourceException when accessing resource wrapper for .resx file nested under .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

When nesting a `.resx` file under a `.cs` file using the `DependentUpon` element in the `.csproj` file and then accessing a resource using the wrapper a `MissingManifestResourceException` is thrown.

The message reads:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Namespace.Resource.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Assembly" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Example code:

```
MessageBox.Show(Resource.Key);
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? :)

Comment: [MissingManifestResourceException](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23%20MissingManifestResourceException) doing a google search on the exact exception can yield plenty of good results to help your case

Comment: @DJKRAZE Please read the whole question (and following answer). This is not answered by any Google result I was able to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSBuild target `PrepareResourceNames` (on which `PrepareResources`, which also calls `ResGen`, depends on) calls a task called `CreateManifestResourceName`.
[see `Microsoft.Common.targets`]

This task creates the name of the `.resources` file. For C# the actual method that creates the name is `CreateManifestNameImpl` in `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CreateCSharpManifestResourceName`. This method checks whether the `.resx` file has a `.cs` file as parent. In that case it searches the `.cs` file for the first fully qualified class name it can find and takes it as the `.resources` file name.
[see `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll`]

The `.resx` wrapper does not expect this file name change and thus an exception is thrown.

I guess this behavior was implemented for WinForms localization which nests its resources under the corresponding form or control.

I decided not to nest the `.resx` files. A possible solution could be to implement a `CreateCustomManifestResourceName` task for which MSBuild provides a hook.

Comment: I'm trying to nest `.resx` in a `.cs` and it is throwing that exception. I really wanted the nesting to work, have you figured out somehow?

Comment: @JobaDiniz No, it wasn't worth the hassle. Overriding that hook is probably the way to go but I have never actually tried it.